# Is it possible to detect typed number in dialer

Tags: java, android

Some hidden settings require to type codes like `*#06#` in dialer.
Is it possible to create an app that does something when it detects a specific code like that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a `USSD based application` then below link can help.

[Read USSD messages in Android](http://umeshisran4android.blogspot.com/2015/11/how-to-readparse-ussd-messages.html)

However, if you want to simply `dial a USSD content` add respective permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file as below and try :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />


private void dialUSSD(String uriString) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uriString));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure, the link you give seems to explain how to handle valid codes, what I want is to detect someone typed #1234# (for exemple) and show my app if he does.

Comment: I found an example for ussd and I receive an event in my app for any ussd message but not the number typed, as I though it seems to work only for valid message...